# Extra table values using XPath and Yahoo Pipe?

Tags: xpath, yahoo-pipes

I'd like to track the appearance of new values in a table via an RSS feed. Specifically, that is new competitions in http://www.kaggle.com/competitions

So I registered for Yahoo Pipes, found the XPath with Firefox XPath Checker to be

```
id('competitions-table')/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/a/h4
```

and used the Pipis XPath Fetch module. I'd expect the list of competition names, however, I get zero results :/

Am I doing it incorrectly? Any other suggestions to accomplish that?

Comment: Try to remove `tbody`

Comment: Hmm, didn't work either. Maybe the `id` part doesn't work. I finally had some success with `//tr/td[1]/div/h4/a/text()`. But I wouldn't know what to do if I really need to address an exact table :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: `//table[@id='competitions-table']//tr//h4`